# Low Allocation Drawing in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, garbage-collection

I am having some serious issues with WPF and using `DrawingContext`, or specifically `VisualDrawingContext` coming from overriding `OnRender` on an element or if using `DrawingVisual.RenderOpen()`.

The problem is this allocates a lot. For example, it seems to be allocating a  `byte[]` buffer each time a drawing context is used.

Examples, of how drawing context is used.

```
using (var drawingContext = m_drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
{
    // Many different drawingContext.Draw calls
    // E.g. DrawEllipse, DrawRectangle etc.
}
```

or

```
override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
{
    // Many different drawingContext.Draw calls
    // E.g. DrawEllipse, DrawRectangle etc.
}
```

This causes a lot of allocations, causing some unwanted garbage collections. So yes I need this, and please stay on topic :).

What are the options for drawing in WPF with zero or low number of managed heap allocations? Reusing objects is fine, but I have yet to find a way to do this... or doesn't then have issues with `DependencyProperty` and allocations around/inside it.

I do know about `WritableBitmapEx` but was hoping for a solution that does not involve rasterising to predefined bitmap, but instead proper "vector" graphics that can still be zoomed for example.

NOTE: CPU usage is a concern but much less than the massive garbage pressure caused by this.

UPDATE: I am looking for a solution for .NET Framework 4.5+, if there is anything in later versions e.g. 4.7 that might help answer this then that is fine. But it is for the desktop .NET Framework.

UPDATE 2: A brief description of the two main scenarios. All examples have been profiled with `CLRProfiler`, and it shows clearly that lots of allocations occur due to this and that this is a problem for our use case. Note that this is example code intended to convey the principles not the exact code.

**A**: This scenario is shown below. Basically, an image is shown and some overlay graphics are drawn via a custom `DrawingVisualControl`, which then uses `using (var drawingContext = m_drawingVisual.RenderOpen())` to get a drawing context and then draws via that. Lots of ellipse, rectangles and text is drawn. This example also shows some scaling stuff, this is just for zooming etc.

```
<Viewbox x:Name="ImageViewbox"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid x:Name="ImageGrid" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" ClipToBounds="True">
        <Grid.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform x:Name="ImageTransform" CenterX="0" CenterY="0" 
                            ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=ImageScaleSlider, Path=Value}"
                            ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=ImageScaleSlider, Path=Value}" />
        </Grid.LayoutTransform>
        <Image x:Name="ImageSource" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
               MouseMove="ImageSource_MouseMove" /> 
        <v:DrawingVisualControl x:Name="DrawingVisualControl" Visual="{Binding DrawingVisual}" 
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
                                RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" 
                                IsHitTestVisible="False" />
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

The `DrawingVisualControl is defined as:

```
public class DrawingVisualControl : FrameworkElement
{
    public DrawingVisual Visual
    {
        get { return GetValue(DrawingVisualProperty) as DrawingVisual; }
        set { SetValue(DrawingVisualProperty, value); }
    }

    private void UpdateDrawingVisual(DrawingVisual visual)
    {
        var oldVisual = Visual;
        if (oldVisual != null)
        {
            RemoveVisualChild(oldVisual);
            RemoveLogicalChild(oldVisual);
        }

        AddVisualChild(visual);
        AddLogicalChild(visual);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DrawingVisualProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("Visual", 
                                      typeof(DrawingVisual),
                                      typeof(DrawingVisualControl),
                                      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnDrawingVisualChanged));

    private static void OnDrawingVisualChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dcv = d as DrawingVisualControl;
        if (dcv == null) { return; }

        var visual = e.NewValue as DrawingVisual;
        if (visual == null) { return; }

        dcv.UpdateDrawingVisual(visual);
    }

    protected override int VisualChildrenCount
    {
        get { return (Visual != null) ? 1 : 0; }
    }

    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
    {
        return this.Visual;
    }
}
```

**B**: The second scenario involves drawing a moving "grid" of data e.g. 20 rows of 100 columns, with elements consisting of a border and text with different colors to display some status. The grid moves depending on external input, and for now is only updated 5-10 times per second. 30 fps would be better. This, thus, updates 2000 items in an `ObservableCollection` tied to a `ListBox` (with `VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"`) and the `ItemsPanel` being a `Canvas`. We can't even show this during our normal use case, since it allocates so much that the GC pauses become way too long and frequent.

```
<ListBox x:Name="Items" Background="Black" 
     VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ElementViewModel}">
            <Border Width="{Binding Width_mm}" Height="{Binding Height_mm}"
                    Background="{Binding BackgroundColor}" 
                    BorderBrush="{Binding BorderColor}" 
                    BorderThickness="3">
                <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding DrawColor}" Padding="0" Margin="0"
                   Text="{Binding TextResult}" FontSize="{Binding FontSize_mm}" 
                   TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X_mm}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y_mm}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas IsItemsHost="True"
                Width="{Binding CanvasWidth_mm}"
                Height="{Binding CanvasHeight_mm}"
                />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

There is a lot of data binding here, and the box'ing of value types do incur a lot of allocations, but that is not the main problem here. It is the allocations done by WPF.

Comment: Note I have also read and tried running the examples from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd483292.aspx but this has allocations too...

Comment: On which .NET Version are you running this?

Comment: Added a comment about .NET version e.g. .NET Framework 4.5+.

Comment: With .NET 4.6.2 the heavy GC blocking times of WPF have become much better. See http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2016/04/14/174476.aspx. Try and compare your tests on .NET 4.6.2.

Comment: it's not really an answer to the question, but if you search performance, it's better to avoid overriding OnRender, unless you have very very specifc needs. It's better to *compose* a scene with existing objects, shapes, etc. and let the engine render it, rather than override OnRender. You talk about Ellipse, Rectangle, etc. It's better to add these as children to visuals/elements, instead of drawing them manually.

Comment: @SimonMourier thanks for the comment. I have tried this as well, but this has a lot of allocations too, also see the link I referred to in the other comment, I was hoping someone could show how one could "compose a scene" and update a scene with zero or low number of allocations using reuseable object etc. Perhaps some tricks around notify property changed etc. But do all visuals not render via OnRender and a drawing context anyway?

Comment: @nietras Please add details about what kind of scene you are actually rendering. Is it (for instance) a fixed set of shapes, that just move or otherwise change appearance? Or do you have to add/remove shapes all the time?

Comment: @nietras Please note I did not say you need to upgrade your project to compile against .NET 4.6.2 or later. You only need to execute your .NET 4.5 compiled WPF application against a .NET Runtime >= 4.6.2 to get the performance benefits. If your customers are running .NET 4.5. it will still run but at slower perf. Please measure your scenario and post results. That would be really interesting how much you did get out of that. If you have multiple threads drawing things then you should consider concurent server gc to lessen GC pause times at lot.

Comment: @AloisKraus I know. The runtime needs to be upgraded on the machine it is running :)

Comment: Added some example code, not complete though. I will try to add some profiling data as well that shows the allocations I am talking about, hopefully soon.

Comment: I have created a github repo show casing some of this https://github.com/nietras/WpfDrawingAllocations but from what I gather all UIElements use `OnRender` with drawing context for persisting the draw vector operations, so it cannot be done better than using the DrawingContext, but somehow it must be possible to get a reuseable DrawingContext that is not allocated each time a render is done...?

Comment: Added new solution using GDI+ and WriteableBitmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WinForms `Canvas` solution has some issues, especially the so-called "airspace" issues due to how `WindowsFormsHost` interacts with WPF. To keep it short, this means that no WPF visuals can be drawn on top of the host.

This can be solved by recognizing that since we have to double buffer anyway, we might as well buffer into a `WriteableBitmap` that can then be drawn as usual via an `Image` control.

This can be fascillitated by using a utility class like the below:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows;
using SWM = System.Windows.Media;
using SWMI = System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

public class GdiGraphicsWriteableBitmap
{
    readonly Action<Rectangle, Graphics> m_draw;
    SWMI.WriteableBitmap m_wpfBitmap = null;
    Bitmap m_gdiBitmap = null;

    public GdiGraphicsWriteableBitmap(Action<Rectangle, Graphics> draw)
    {
        if (draw == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(draw)); }
        m_draw = draw;
    }

    public SWMI.WriteableBitmap WriteableBitmap => m_wpfBitmap;

    public bool IfNewSizeResizeAndDraw(int width, int height)
    {
        if (m_wpfBitmap == null ||
            m_wpfBitmap.PixelHeight != height ||
            m_wpfBitmap.PixelWidth != width)
        {
            Reset();
            // Can't dispose wpf
            const double Dpi = 96;
            m_wpfBitmap = new SWMI.WriteableBitmap(width, height, Dpi, Dpi,
                SWM.PixelFormats.Bgr24, null);
            var ptr = m_wpfBitmap.BackBuffer;
            m_gdiBitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, m_wpfBitmap.BackBufferStride,
                System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, ptr);

            Draw();

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void Draw()
    {
        if (m_wpfBitmap != null)
        {
            m_wpfBitmap.Lock();
            int width = m_wpfBitmap.PixelWidth;
            int height = m_wpfBitmap.PixelHeight;
            {
                using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(m_gdiBitmap))
                {
                    m_draw(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), g);
                }
            }
            m_wpfBitmap.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, width, height));
            m_wpfBitmap.Unlock();
        }
    }

    // If window containing this is not shown, one can Reset to stop draw or similar...
    public void Reset()
    {
        m_gdiBitmap?.Dispose();
        m_wpfBitmap = null;
    }
}
```

And then binding the `ImageSource` to an `Image` in XAML:

```
    <Grid x:Name="ImageContainer" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <Image x:Name="ImageSource" 
               RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        </Image>
    </Grid>
```

And the handling resize on the Grid to make the WriteableBitmap match in size e.g.:

```
public partial class SomeView : UserControl
{
    ISizeChangedViewModel m_viewModel = null;

    public SomeView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContextChanged += OnDataContextChanged;
    }

    void OnDataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (m_viewModel != null)
        {
            this.ImageContainer.SizeChanged -= ImageSource_SizeChanged;
        }
        m_viewModel = e.NewValue as ISizeChangedViewModel;
        if (m_viewModel != null)
        {
            this.ImageContainer.SizeChanged += ImageSource_SizeChanged;
        }
    }

    private void ImageSource_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var newSize = e.NewSize;
        var width = (int)Math.Round(newSize.Width);
        var height = (int)Math.Round(newSize.Height);
        m_viewModel?.SizeChanged(width, height);
    }
}
```

This way you can use WinForms/GDI+ for drawing with zero heap allocations and even `WriteableBitmapEx` if you prefer. Note that you then get great `DrawString` support with GDI+ incl. `MeasureString`.

The drawback is this is rasterized and sometimes can have some interpolation issues. So be sure to also set `UseLayoutRounding="True"` on the parent window/user control.

Answer (score 1):

### Some Inputs

Your piece of code is not available so I can suggest only.
When its comes to performance, use profiling tools available from Microsoft.
You can find the tools [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767(v=vs.110).aspx)

The one more important link where you can read is [WPF graphics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/wpf-graphics-rendering-overview)

Note:- 
***Try using Drawing Group***

Comment: Added some example code. DrawingGroup doesn't seem to help, but perhaps using it wrong.

Comment: @nietras As far i understood. U modify values in Listbox and that values are changed in collection which are also bound to Grid or Data Grid? After the value updates your grid cell react to the changes is it? By Moving means that you can drag you grid here and there ? Before I make further assumptions. trying using recycling properties on canvas and grids

Comment: recycling is used (virtualizing panel) and the problem is not that too many view objects are created. it is the data binding low level stuff deep in wpf that cause the issues. frugal list, byte[], freezablecontextpair[] allocs etc. I also take care to reuse view model objects and not actually change the observablecollection as such but just the position properties.

Answer (score 1):

Use [WindowsFormsHost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost(v=vs.110).aspx) as described in [Walkthrough: Hosting a Windows Forms Control in WPF by Using XAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-hosting-a-windows-forms-control-in-wpf-by-using-xaml) and GDI+ for drawing instead. This isn't a perfect solution, but the - for now - best alternative I have been able to find.

```
<Grid>
    <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="WinFormsHost>
        <custom:Canvas x:Name="Canvas" />
    </WindowsFormsHost>
</Grid>
```

And then create a custom control and override `OnPaint`, something like:

```
public partial class Canvas 
    : UserControl
{
    // Implementing custom double buffered graphics, since this is a lot
    // faster both when drawing and with respect to GC, since normal
    // double buffered graphics leaks disposable objects that the GC needs to finalize
    protected BufferedGraphicsContext m_bufferedGraphicsContext = 
        new BufferedGraphicsContext();
    protected BufferedGraphics m_bufferedGraphics = null;
    protected Rectangle m_currentClientRectangle = new Rectangle();

    public Canvas()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Setup();
    }

    private void Setup()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
                 ControlStyles.Opaque | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
        DoubleBuffered = false;

        this.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }

    private void DisposeManagedResources()
    {
        m_bufferedGraphicsContext.Dispose();
        if (m_bufferedGraphics != null)
        {
            m_bufferedGraphics.Dispose();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // Background paint is done in OnPaint
        // This reduces the "leaks" of System.Windows.Forms.Internal.DeviceContext 
        // and the amount of "GC" handles created considerably
        // as found by using CLR Profiler
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // Specifically not calling base here since we draw entire area ourselves
        // base.OnPaint(e);
        // Should this be disposed? 
        using (e)
        using (var targetGraphics = e.Graphics)
        {
            ReallocBufferedGraphics(targetGraphics);

            // Use buffered graphics object
            var graphics = m_bufferedGraphics.Graphics;
            // Raise paint event
            PaintEvent?.Invoke(this.ClientRectangle, e.ClipRectangle, graphics);

            // Render to target graphics i.e. paint event args graphics
            m_bufferedGraphics.Render(targetGraphics);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void ReallocBufferedGraphics(Graphics graphics)
    {
        Rectangle newClientRectangle = this.ClientRectangle;

        // Realloc if new client rectangle is not contained within the current
        // or if no buffered graphics exists
        bool reallocBufferedGraphics = ShouldBufferBeReallocated(newClientRectangle);
        if (reallocBufferedGraphics)
        {
            if (m_bufferedGraphics != null)
            {
                m_bufferedGraphics.Dispose();
            }
            m_bufferedGraphics = m_bufferedGraphicsContext.Allocate(
                 graphics, newClientRectangle);
            m_currentClientRectangle = newClientRectangle;
        }
    }

    protected virtual bool ShouldBufferBeReallocated(Rectangle newClientRectangle)
    {
        return !m_currentClientRectangle.Contains(newClientRectangle) || 
                m_bufferedGraphics == null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// PaintEvent with <c>clientRectangle, clipRectangle, graphics</c> for the canvas.
    /// </summary>
    public event Action<Rectangle, Rectangle, Graphics> PaintEvent;
}
```

UPDATE: Updated Canvas control to truly be **zero** heap allocations.